# Metric Spaces: Uniform Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

i've entered my next year after having resat the previous year and i feel slightly rusty. i'm now reading metric spaces and would like some clarification in particular about uniform convergence with metric spaces.

so!

> Let X be a set and (Y,d) a metric space; For a sequence of functions $f_n:X \rightarrow Y$ to converge pointwise we need there to exist a function $f: X \rightarrow Y%$ such that $(\forall x\in X)~[\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} d(f_n(x),f(x))=0]$

so for my understanding for all the elements in $X$ the sequence of functions needs to converge to a single function. where as Uniform convergence criteria is that

> $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{x \in X} d(f_n(x),f(x))=0$

IE the largest elements of the sequence  of functions converge to the largest element in $f$ (if im remembering correctly please by all means correct me i appreciate it)

but onto my main issue.

from an example;

> let $f_n:[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{n+x}.$ then $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise (this makes sense) to $f(x)=x, x \geq 0$ but $f_n$ does not converge uniformly since
>
> $$|f_n \left( \frac{n}{2} \right)-f \left( \frac{n}{2} \right)|=\frac{n}{6}\geq \frac{1}{6}$$

so in the above case we had a value of x in $[0, \infty),$ in which $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{x \in X} d(f_n(x),f(x)) \neq 0$

how did they find this value of x is my question.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to find some value of $x$ so that we can show 
$$
\sup_{x\in [0,\infty)}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\not\to 0
$$
one way to do this is examine some sequence of $x_n$'s for which the difference 
$$
|f_n(x)-f(x)|
$$
tends to some nonzero constant in $n$, or worse, as they have found here, is unbounded in $n$.

In your example, an $x$ is selected to get the second, much worse case. Since along this sequence, we have
$$
\bigg|f_n\bigg(\frac{n}{2}\bigg)-\frac{n}{2}\bigg|=\frac{n}{6}\to \infty
$$
as $n\to \infty$. Thus, there is no way to insure the supremum over all $x$ tends to $0$.

If the question is how did they arrive at this $x$ in a nitty gritty sense, one idea would be to play around with some $x$ a function of $n$ with the proper order to insure the difference blows up in $n$. Here, if we take $x$ to be a linear function of $n$, then we will have a quadratic in $n$ in the numerator, and a linear function in $n$ in the denominator. That ought to do.

As for your interpretation of what 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{x\in X}d(f(x),f_n(x))=0
$$
means, this is really not right. What this is saying is that the worst the difference between $f(x)$ and $f_n(x)$ for any $x$ gets really small as $n$ gets really big.

Comment: ok first to sort out my understanding of lim sup d.

as a restatement of what you've said is $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}sup d(.... = 0$$ means the largest difference between $f(x)$ and $f_n(x)$ tends to zero as n tends to infinity. no matter what the value of x...

is this a correct restatement? as for how they came to $x = \frac{n}{2}$ in particular it sounds like fancy manipulation of values of x with an end goal in mind. but does that not presupposes the type of convergence? ie you have prior knowledge whether its pointwise or uniform before you try to prove it?

Comment: for the first part, yes that is correct.  yes, one can at least suspect at first glance that this is not going to be uniform convergence. Think about what happens when $x$ is very large, won't we need a bigger $n$ to get close to x?

Answer (score 2):

You line "IE the largest elements of the sequence of functions converge to the largest element in f" is wrong. It not that the largest elements converge, it's that the largest difference between $f_n$ and $f$ converges to zero. Stated another way, $f_n\to f$ uniformly if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
d(f_n(x),f(x))< \varepsilon, \quad \text{for all $x\in X$ and all $n\ge N$.}
$$
Contrast this to having $f_n\to f$ pointwise, which just means for each $x\in X$ and $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
d(f_n(x),f(x))< \varepsilon, \quad \text{for all $n\ge N$.}
$$
Indeed, in the definition of uniform convergence, the $N$ we find must work for any $x$, while in the definition of pointwise convergence, each $x$ gets it's own $N$.

As for your example, let's rewrite $f_n$ as
$$
f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{n+x} = \frac{x}{\frac{1}{n}(n+x)} = \frac{x}{1+\frac{x}{n}}.
$$
Now it is obvious that $f_n(x)\to x$ for every $x\in[0,\infty)$, so that $f_n\to f$ pointwise.

To see why $f_n\not\to f$ uniformly, it's instructive to try proving it. Okay, so let's fix $\varepsilon>0$. We want to find $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
|f_n(x)-f(x)|< \varepsilon, \quad\text{for $x\in [0,\infty)$ and $n\ge N$}.
$$
Well
\begin{align*}
|f_n(x)-f(x)|
&= \left|\frac{nx}{n+x}-x\right|
= \frac{x^2}{n+x}.
\end{align*}
No matter how large $n$ is there will always be $x\in[0,\infty)$ so that the above is at least $\varepsilon$. Indeed, by taking $x=n/2$, the above becomes
$$
\frac{(n/2)^2}{n+(n/2)}=\frac{n}{6},
$$
which is clearly not less than $\varepsilon>0$ for large enough $n$.
I'm not sure why they made the particular choice of $x=n/2$. Setting $x=n$ works just as easily.